# Send data in server timezone issue

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I've spent a lot of time trying to understand the timezones. But i'm still confused.

**Design:**

1) Server in a different time zone than client.

2) I got the following Info in API call:

> /api/config/v1/system/time

```
{
  "timeZoneOffset": -18000000, (milli sec)
  "serverTimeUTC": 1485332569157,
  "serverTime": "Wed Jan 25 03:22:49 EST 2017",
  "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
}
```

3) I have no access on the server. (Can't really change any code there!)

4) I have a complete access on client side. (Javascript)

**Problem/Requirement:**

- I want to take clients time (PST, CST etc) and send it in the corresponding server time. (Whatever timezone the server is in) (Not necessarily UTC).

**My code:**

I've attempted the following but still confused as where I'm going:

```
    getServerTimeZone: function(newTime){

        var _this = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/config/v1/system/time'
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            if(!newTime){
                newTime = new Date();
            }
            //Get Server Timezone and offset
            //Offset is in milli sec. Converting it to hours
            var serverTimeOffset = data.timeZoneOffset / (60 * 60 * 1000);

            // Get current timezone offset for host device
            var x = new Date();
       var clientCurrentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

            //Calculate the difference
            var actualOffset = Math.abs(clientCurrentTimeZoneOffsetInHours - serverTimeOffset);

            //Format actual time in relative to server time
            serverTime = moment.utc(newTime).zone(actualOffset).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A');
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the modified code below, i used moment js manipulation feature utcOffset so we can change the timezone of the clients date.

It will give us the corresponding server date/time based on the date/time on the client.

getServerTimeZone: function(newTime){

```
var _this = this;
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/config/v1/system/time'
})
.done(function(data) {
    if(!newTime){
        newTime = new Date();
    }
        //Get Server Timezone and offset
        //Offset is in milli sec. Converting it to hours
        var serverTimeOffset = data.timeZoneOffset / (60 * 60 * 1000);

        // Get current timezone offset for host device
        var x = new Date();
        var clientCurrentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

        // change the timezone using utcOffset
        serverTime = moment(x).utcOffset(serverTimeOffset).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A');
    });
```

},

You can test it here, i used -5 offset.

https://jsbin.com/puvutevomo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I love you! Thank you so much! How did I miss that.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the requirement correctly you shouldn't need to send any timezone specific information up to the server. When a date/time is given in [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (and has an x on the end) it is in UTC format. Timezones at that point are irrelevant and only used for display purposes.

moment will display that date/time in the user's correct timezone automatically (based on the browser settings).

```
var d = moment('2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z');
console.log(d.format('llll')); //This will output the date/time relative to the user's timezone automatically

var sendToServer = d.toISOString() //send this string up to the server. It is in UTC format.
```

Comment: But my requirement wasn't that. I want to send the date/time in the 'corresponding' server's timezone. Not in UTC. The reason why i'm saying is because there is a cron(on server) which runs on the local time (Not UTC)

Comment: What date format does the server accept? Should still work absolutely fine if the server stores the dates in ISO8601 format (doesn't matter what time the cron job runs, it would take into account the timezone difference as part of the cron job itself).

Comment: The server accepts only localtime. The server does not store dates in ISO8601 format. Is it possible to send the data back in the server's timezone?